# How to return correct format JsonString

Tags: java, json

```
static String Q2(String json1, String json2, String json3){
    // given three JSON Strings, combine them into a single JSON String.
    //
    // The inputs are in the format:
    // json1: {"number":9}
    // json2: [10,14,0,12] <-- any number of ints
    // json3: [{"key1":4},{"key2":5}] <-- always 2 objects
    //
    // and the output must be in the format:
    // {"number":9,"array":[10,14,0,12],"key1":4,"key2":5}

    JsonObject array = new JsonObject();
    array.add("array", json2);

    JsonArray ans = new JsonArray();
    ans.add(json1);
    ans.add(array);
    ans.add(json3);

    String data = ans.toString();
    String formatted = data.replaceAll("\\\\", "");

    return formatted;
}
```

On the assignment grader it reads:

```
Incorrect on input: [{"number":9}, [10,14,0,12], [{"key1":4},{"key2":5}]]
Expected output : {"number":9,"array":[10,14,0,12],"key1":4,"key2":5}
Your output     : "{"number":9}",{"array":"[10,14,0,12]"},"[{"key1":4},{"key2":5}]"
```

The only difference I see between my output and the expected output are the brackets, curly brackets, and quotes. How can I remove the specific ones that are not needed?

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest to read your input:

```
JsonReader reader1 = Json.createReader(new StringReader(json1));
JsonReader reader2 = Json.createReader(new StringReader(json2));
JsonReader reader3 = Json.createReader(new StringReader(json3));
```

Then convert it into your objects:

```
// The inputs are in the format:
// json1: {"number":9}
// json2: [10,14,0,12] <-- any number of ints
// json3: [{"key1":4},{"key2":5}] <-- always 2 objects

JsonObject read1 = reader1.readObject();
JsonArray read2 = reader2.readArray();
JsonArray read3 = reader3.readArray();
```

Then create an `JsonObjectBuilder` and merge everything into it:

```
JsonObjectBuilder obj = Json.createObjectBuilder();

read1.forEach((a,b) -> { 
  obj.add(a, b);
} );

obj.add("array", read2);

read3.forEach(v -> { 
  ((JsonObject)v).forEach((key,value) -> obj.add(key, value));
});

System.out.println(obj.build().toString());
```

Prints:

```
{"number":9,"array":[10,14,0,12],"key1":4,"key2":5}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try that, but i'd do something like this.

```
    //with jackson
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode j1 = mapper.readTree(json1);
    //HINT: I'm not sure if json array without root {} is a valid json, but this should work -> String[] sortings = mapper.readValue(json2,TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructArrayType(String.class));
    JsonNode j2 = mapper.readTree(json2);
    JsonNode j3 = mapper.readTree(json3);
    ObjectNode jNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
    //add all nodes from j1 to json root, there is only one, but if there will be more it will work.
    j1.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(fieldName -> jNode.replace(fieldName,j1.get(fieldName)));
    //add json array under array field
    jNode.set("array", j2);
    //add all nodes from j3 to json root, if exist for example array or number, they will be replaced!
    j3.forEach(node -> node.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(fieldName -> jNode.replace(fieldName,j1.get(fieldName))));

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(jNode))
```